# Error page redirect not working with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, xampp, apache2

I'm configuring server to use a custom error page and want the server to respond with an **error 404** on a direct request.
Also I use `mod_rewrite` so I can access the page without writing file extension.
When I access `localhost/error.php` it gets redirected with **code 404** but with `localhost/error` it doesn't get redirected.

This is my code in configs.

```
#Remove extensions
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Errors
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

#Redirect
<Files "index.php">
    <If "-z %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}">
        RedirectMatch 404 ^/error.php$
    </If>
</Files>
```

Comment: What code do you have in your `error.php` file? When you request `/error.php` directly, the code in your config (`.htaccess`?) doesn't actually do anything. If you are seeing a 404 HTTP status then this must be generated by the PHP code?

Comment: _"but with localhost/error it doesn't get redirected"_ - why should it, you rewrote that request to error.php, which exists.

Comment: @MrWhite `error.php` gets a status with `REDIRECT_STATUS` variable and outputs an error message. When I directly request it without the extension, it has a 202 OK status, but the .htaccess code should redirect it with a 404. If I generate a 404 in PHP with `header()`, it shows the browser's default error page, not `error .php`.

Comment: `RedirectMatch` should redirect to `error.php` with a status 404, but when I directly request it without extension it has 202.

Comment: When you request `/error` (without an extension) your first rule rewrites the request to `error.php`. So this wouldn't result in a 404 unless your PHP script explicitly returns a 404 status. If you generate a 404 in PHP with `header()` then it won't use the Apache `ErrorDocument`, you would need to generate the HTML response in PHP. Your `RedirectMatch 404` directive only applies when requesting `index.php`.

Comment: "without the extension, it has a 202 OK status" - not sure why you would get a 20**2** here; I would expect a 200 OK response (unless your script overrides this).